# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker - cannot integrate

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker. I installed packages for bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap and jquery. When I load the app I get the error

```
ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:7341 Uncaught TypeError: angular.$$csp is not a function
```

My index.html is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  <!--Controllers-->
  <script src="js/controllers/first-controller.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  <script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked version compatibility between your various scripts?  Also, be aware that load order matters.  You want to include jQuery and ui-bootstrap before your app and controller.

Comment: First, you have to load the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js before your first-controller.js

Comment: I downloaded v1.3.3 for angular-ui-bootstrap and v3.3.6 for bootstrap, but I did't find recommended version for jQuery

Comment: The problem was with the version of Angular - it was too low